# Returning only the first 10 record - Redis OM

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, redisearch, redis-om-spring

I’m using Redis OM for spring boot, I am having trouble querying objects because it only returns the first 10 records.

Repository Class:

```
public interface RedisBillerRepository extends RedisDocumentRepository<Biller, Long> {
  List<Biller> findByClientIds(String clientId);
}
```

Is there a way to return ALL the objects with the specific clientId? Not the first 10 only.

Answer (score 3):

The only way which i found was with the interface Page. For example your Repository would look like this:

```
public interface RedisBillerRepository extends RedisDocumentRepository<Biller, Long> {
    Page<Biller> findByClientIds(String clientId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And your class could look like this

```
public class BillerService {

@Autowired
RedisBillerRepository redisBillerRepository;


public List<Biller> getAllClientsById(String clientId){
    Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 500000);
    Page<Biller> foundBillers = redisBillerRepository.findByClientIds(clientId, pageRequest);
    List<Biller> billersAsList = foundBillers.getContent();
    return billersAsList;
}
```

}

You have to set the limit for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the library... @member2 is correct. RediSearch currently has a default for the underlying `FT.SEARCH` (https://redis.io/commands/ft.search/) method of returning the first 10 records found. To override that, the only way to do so currently is to use the Pagination constructs in Spring.

<s>I will expose a configuration parameter in upcoming versions to set the MAX globally.</s>

Now there are officially two ways:

1. Use Spring's Pageable class like https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring/blob/main/redis-om-spring/src/test/java/com/redis/om/spring/annotations/document/fixtures/MyDocRepository.java#L57 then see example of how to use it here https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring/blob/main/redis-om-spring/src/test/java/com/redis/om/spring/annotations/document/RedisDocumentSearchTest.java#L143
2. Configure a default LIMIT for all your queries as shown here https://github.com/redis/redis-om-spring/blob/main/redis-om-spring/src/test/resources/application.yaml

```yaml
redis:
  om:
    spring:
      repository:
        query:
          limit: 20
```

Comment: I have configured the `limit` parameter in my `application.yml` ... having a method in my `RedisEnhancedRepository` defined as `Iterable<Job> findAllByValidIsAndTimestampIsBetween(Boolean valid, Long fromTimestamp, Long toTimestamp);` but calling this method still just returns 10 results.